How not to put # (pound hash) in column 0?
I read: How do I turn off the feature where the pound sign is forced to 0 position?
I could not resolve the issue of the # always going to the beginning of a line.
What I really want is for # to not be treated any differently from regular letters a-z as far as indentation goes.
I looked in the /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/* files, but could not see anything obvious for # indentation.

what have you tried?

What type of file are you editing? Makefiles? C? C++? Something else?

In order to help you we would need the version of Vim you are using (i.e. the result of the :version Vim command) it seems a flavor of Vim 8.0 and the filetype of the buffer (i.e. the result of the :set ft? Vim command). The pound # is used for commenting in a large set of language :-)

What is the result of the :verbose set smartindent? command?

Try setlocal cinkeys-=0#. This is what I use in my Verilog setting because the same 'problem' annoyed me in the past.

Welcome to the site. I edited to remove your remark "The learning curve for vim programming seems pretty steep." This wasn't done to censor criticism (hence this comment for transparency) but because it's basically unrelated to your question. I use to say: Learn Vim. In only 10 years, you'll be more productive than today :-)

The learning curve is only steep if you naively expect the "learning" to happen organically, one decontextualized video/tweet/post/question/thread at a time. Following :help user-manual instead, makes for a very short and gentle curve.

IIn addition to my last comment, if you don't use cindent, try setlocal indentkeys-=0#

"setlocal cinkeys-=0#" works !

Also,    "smartindent" is not set, and "cindent" is set.  This is life changing :-) thanks for the help !

You should [edit] clarifications into your question. Questions should be self-contained to be useful to future readers. Comments may go away at some point in the future.

setlocal cinkeys-=0# works!
It prevents moving "#" to column 0.
I do have cindent set.

You probably don't want cindent set except in buffers with C-like syntax, just FYI
